# how to sum inputs from a textbox using a list and display it in a label in C#

Tags: c#, list

hey guys i just to display the sum of a list i made using textbox inputs into a label

```
List<double> Val = new List<double>();
            expenses.total = 0.0;
            Val.Add(expenses.Amount);
            expenses.total += Val.Sum();
            //displays the total on the label
            Display.Text = Convert.ToString(expenses.total);
```

i did this but every time i run the code, the sum does not display, instead the last value entered displays

Comment: what did you see in the debugger? What is the value in expenses.Amount

Comment: I see the value I typed in, however, the value in the list is count = 0, and the value in expenses. total is also 0

Comment: Please define your expenses variable. Is it a class? If Display is the label, what is the textBox? How are numbers separated in it? Is the code you show part of a loop? If not, the Val.Add will only add once.